# How to get hashmap response using Retrofit 2

Tags: android, hashmap, retrofit2

I am trying to fetch json object response using retrofit 2. I used hashmap as the keys are dynamic. Here is my response class :

```
public class Countries {

    private Map<String, Model> datas;

    public Map<String, Model> getDatas() {
        return datas;
    }
}
```

And the `Model` class is :

```
public class Model {

    @SerializedName("country_name")
    private String country_name;
    @SerializedName("continent_name")
    private String continent_name;

    public String getCountry_name() {
        return country_name;
    }

    public String getContinent_name() {
        return continent_name;
    }
}
```

So far, i've tried to handle the response like this :

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<Countries>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Countries> call, Response<Countries> response) {

                Map<String, Model> map = new HashMap<String, Model>();
                map = response.body().getDatas();

                for (String keys: map.keySet()) {
                    // myCode;
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Countries> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

And this error occurs :

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'java.util.Set java.util.Map.keySet()' on a null object reference

JSON response looks like this :

```
{
    "0": {
        "country_name": "Argentina",
        "continent_name": "South America"
    },
    "1": {
        "country_name": "Germany",
        "continent_name": "Europe"
    }
}
```

So how can I get the response in HashMap?

Comment: Can you capture the json string your call is returning and post it here?

Comment: @Ben p., I have added the json response in the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `Call<Countries>` when you should be using `Call<Map<String, Model>>`. Your response has no field named "datas"; it's just a plain map of `String` to `Model` objects.

Delete the `Countries` class and replace all references to it in your networking code with `Map<String, Model>`.

Answer (score 2):

Your method `getDatas()` retruns `null` because you did not assign the data to it.

You should do it this way to get the data:

```
map = response.body().datas;
```

Instead of:

```
map = response.body().getDatas();
```

You should also replace this

```
private Map<String, Model> datas;
```

with

```
public Map<String, Model> datas;
```

Your code should look like this.

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<Countries>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Countries> call, Response<Countries> response) {

            Map<String, Model> map = new HashMap<String, Model>();
            map = response.body().datas;

            for (String keys: map.keySet()) {
                // myCode;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Countries> call, Throwable t) {

        }
});
```

Comment: "datas" is a private variable.